# Naturality can be detected on a dense subcategory

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}\def\colim{\text{colim}}$I need this result in less generality, but I'd be happy to know this stronger version holds.

Let $\{\alpha_c : Fc \to Gc\}$ be arrows in a category $D$, indexed by the objects of a category $C$, for two functors $F,G: C\to D$.

Let $A\subseteq C$ be a dense subcategory (meaning that $i : A \hookrightarrow C$ is a dense functor). Then $\alpha$ is a natural transformation *if and only if it is natural on the components $c\in A$ (and with respect to morphisms of $A$)*.

**Edit**: This is not what I wanted to know (and false, see below): instead, I'm trying to prove that there is a unique extension of a natural transformation $Fi\to Gi$ to a natural transformation $F\to G$.

Example: for a functor $K: [I°,Set] \to [I°,Set]$, a natural transformation $\alpha : 1_{[I°,Set]}\to K$ is such if and only if it is natural when restricted to representables.

It is easy to see that the right universal property gives that if $P = \colim y(X_i)$ is a colimit of representables, then there is
$$
P \cong \colim\; y(X_i) \xrightarrow{\colim \alpha_{X_i}} \colim\; Ky(X_i) \to K\big(\colim\; y(X_i)\big) \cong KP
$$
It seems then that all boils down to the fact that the morphism $\colim\; KX\to K(\colim\; X)$ is "natural", i.e.
$$
\begin{CD}
KX @>>> K(\colim_I X_i)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
KY @>>> K(\colim_J Y_j)
\end{CD}
$$
commutes (but how do you induce the right-vertical arrow?).

Comment: [Kelly's first characterization of density](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf#page=91) states this will be true for functors $F$ and $G$ that preserve weighted colimits of shape $A$. Theorem 5.1 (i).

Comment: The identity surely preserves all colimits, but $K$ is any functor, so I can't invoke these assumptions; why is the result true for presheaves then? The result here is the bijection $$Nat(y, Ky) \cong Nat(1, K)$$

Comment: @DerekElkins: That says that any transformation which is natural on $A$ has a unique extension to one natural on $C$.  It doesn't say that _any_ extension to $C$ is automatically natural!

Comment: Maybe I phrased the question in a way which is not equivalent to what I want to prove, dazzled by who-knows-what. What I wanted is to prove that the left Kan extension of Yoneda along itself is the identity, which translates into the bijection above, which translates into the fact that right whiskering with $y$ induces the bijection, which translates into the fact that as soon as you specify $K$ on representables, it has a unique extension to a pointed functor. I can find the arrows with which $K$ is pointed, but I'm stuck proving that these are natural (see comment below).

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right.

Comment: Anyway, I've never wanted that any extension to $C$ is automatically natural, that wasn't the question. I phrased it incorrectly.

Comment: So you are not asking K cocontinuous? If It were It should work. If it is not cocontinuous I think I have a counterexample.

Comment: @Fosco my bad, I got that it is necessary for $F$ to be cocontinuous, for $G$ it is not necessary. Since I did not fully understand the edit I think I will wait for clarifications.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\newcommand{\colim}{\mathop{\rm colim}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\Nat}{\mathop{\rm Nat}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\cancom}[1]{\big((i/#1)\stackrel{\mathrm{pr}_}{→}  \stackrel{i}{→} ℂ\big)}
$$

First, I thank [Ohad Kammar](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ohad.kammar/main.html), [Mathieu Huot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/525482/mathieu-huot) and [Sean Moss](https://www.univ.ox.ac.uk/academics/sean-moss/) who helped me to come up with this answer.

To answer your **EDIT** in a nutshell: the result *doesn't stand* in general when $F$ is not cocontinuous.

Here are two counter-examples to the existence and unicity of your natural transformation extension:

### Counter-example to existence

Let

- $ℂ =  \, ≝ \, X ⟶ Y$ (category with two objects and one non-trivial morphism between them)
- $ \, ≝ \, \mathbb{1}$ (terminal category)
- $i: \begin{cases}
      ↪︎ ℂ  \\
     \ast ⟼ Y
  \end{cases}$
- $F \, ≝ \, \mathrm{const}_Y ∈ [ℂ, ]$ (constant functor sending all the $ℂ$-objects to $Y$)
- $G \, ≝ \, \mathrm{Id}_{ℂ} ∈ [ℂ, ]$

then there is a natural transformation between $Fi: \begin{cases}
   \mathbb{1} ⟶  \\
   \ast ⟼ Y
\end{cases}$ and $Gi: \begin{cases}
   \mathbb{1} ⟶  \\
   \ast ⟼ Y
\end{cases}$ (the identity), but no natural transformation from $F$ to $G$, as there is no morphism from $F(X) = Y$ and $G(X) = X$.

### Counter-example to uniqueness

- As before, let's set $ℂ ≝ \, X ⟶ Y, \;  \, ≝ \, \mathbb{1}, \; i: \begin{cases}
      ↪︎ ℂ  \\
     \ast ⟼ Y
  \end{cases}$
- Let $$ be the category given by

  - two object $X'$ and $Y'$
  - two non-trivial morphisms: $g: X' ⟶ Y'$ and $f: X' ⟶ X'$ such that $$gf = g \qquad \text{ and} \qquad f^2 = \mathrm{id}_{X'}$$
- $F = G: \begin{cases}
    ℂ ⟶  \\
    X ⟼ X' \\
    Y ⟼ Y'
  \end{cases}$

then there is a natural transformation between $Fi: \begin{cases}
   \mathbb{1} ⟶  \\
   \ast ⟼ Y'
\end{cases}$ and $Gi: \begin{cases}
   \mathbb{1} ⟶  \\
   \ast ⟼ Y'
\end{cases}$ (the identity), but two distinct natural transformations from $F$ to $G$ (the identity and the one whose component at $X$ is $f$).

### Fixed statement

Your assertion is true if $F$ is assumed to be **cocontinuous** though:

> Let $F: ℂ ⟶ $ be a **cocontinuous** functor, $G: ℂ ⟶ $ a functor and $ \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} ℂ$ a dense subcategory. There is a unique extension of every natural transformation $Fi ⇒ Gi$ to a natural transformation $F ⇒ G$.

The proof is as shown in the diagram below: for every $c \cong \colim\cancom{c}, \, c' \cong \colim\cancom{c} ∈ ℂ, \, f: c ⟶ c'$:

- there is a cocone from $\cancom{c}\stackrel{F}{→} $ to $G(c)$ (resp. from $\cancom{c'}\stackrel{F}{→} $ to $G(c')$)

  - *indeed*: the green subdiagram commutes (since $Gϕ_1 = G ϕ_2 \circ Gg$ (cocone property) and $Gg \circ α_{ia_1} = α_{ia_2} \circ Fg$ (naturality))

  so there exists a unique corresponding cocone morphism $α_c: F(c) ⟶ G(c)$ (resp. $α_c': F(c') ⟶ G(c')$), due to $F$ being concontinuous
- the two cocones $\cancom{c}\stackrel{F}{→} $ to $G(c)$ obtained by post-composing by $α_c \circ Ff$ and $Gf \circ α_{c'}$ are equal

  - *indeed*: the red subdiagram commutes since $Gϕ_1' \circ α_{ia_1'} = α_{c'} \circ F ϕ_1'$ (colimit property of $F(c')$) and $α_c \circ Ff \circ Fϕ_1' = Gf \circ Gϕ_1' \circ α_{ia_1'}$ (colimit property of $F(c)$))

  so there is a unique cocone morphism from $\cancom{c}\stackrel{F}{→} $ to $G(c)$ for these cocones, and the red square commutes: $Gf \circ α_{c'} = α_c \circ Ff$, which ends the proof.

[image]

[Link to the svg picture](http://younesse.net/assets/StackExchange/naturality-can-be-detected-on-a-dense-subcategory/svg/extension.svg)

By duality, one can also prove that:

> Let $F: ℂ ⟶ $ be a functor, $G: ℂ ⟶ $ a **continuous** functor and $ \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} ℂ$ a co-dense subcategory. There is a unique extension of every natural transformation $Fi ⇒ Gi$ to a natural transformation $F ⇒ G$.

[image]

[Link to the svg picture](http://younesse.net/assets/StackExchange/naturality-can-be-detected-on-a-dense-subcategory/svg/extension_dual.svg)

### Application: Nerve functor fully faithful

With the dual version of the lemma, we get this well-known result as a corollary:

> **Corollary**: If $ℂ \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} $ is dense, the nerve functor
>   $$N_i: \begin{cases}
>    &⟶ \widehat ℂ  \\
>   d &⟼ (i(-), d)
> \end{cases}$$
>   is fully faithful.

[image]

[Link to the svg picture](http://younesse.net/assets/StackExchange/naturality-can-be-detected-on-a-dense-subcategory/svg/nerve.svg)

*Proof*:  We want to prove that for all $d, d' ∈ $:
$$\Nat\Big(\underbrace{(i(-), d)}_{\mathbb{y}_(d)i}, \, \underbrace{(i(-), d')}_{\mathbb{y}_(d')i}\Big) \cong \Nat(d, \, d') \overset{\scriptsize\text{Yoneda lemma}}{\cong} \Nat\Big(\underbrace{(-, d)}_{\mathbb{y}_(d)}, \, \underbrace{(-, d')}_{\mathbb{y}_(d')}\Big)$$

The result follows by applying the dual version of the lemma with $i^{\rm op}$ ($i$ post-composed with the $\rm op$ functor) and $F ≝ \mathbb{y}_(d), \; G ≝ \mathbb{y}_(d')$:

[image]

[Link to the svg picture](http://younesse.net/assets/StackExchange/naturality-can-be-detected-on-a-dense-subcategory/svg/two_arrows.svg)

Answer (score 2):

This is very very false.  You can simply take any natural transformation $Fi\to Gi$, and then define $\alpha_c$ for each $c\not\in A$ to be any map $Fc\to Gc$ at all.  It would be an enormous coincidence if the latter satisfied naturality.

For a simple example, let $C=D=Set$, $F=G=1_{Set}$, and let $A$ consist of just a singleton.  Any $\alpha$ is natural when restricted to $A$, but it's certainly not true that any collection of maps $X\to X$ for each set $X$ defines a natural transformation $1_{Set}\to 1_{Set}$

Comment: I agree with your counterexample, but yet I don't see why, then, the Yoneda embedding of the singleton in $Set$ is dense (as it must be). Motivated by Derek's comment, I think I forgot to take $K$ cocontinuous when instantiating the above bijection. But still I don't see why I need this assumption, as $Lan_yy\cong 1$ should be a general result. What am I missing?

Comment: For the record: given a functor $K : Set \to Set$ there is a family of arrows
$$ X \to colim_X K* \to KX$$
induced by the UP of the colimit and by the fact that $X \cong \coprod_X *$. It seems to me that this is natural if and only if the two squares 
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
X &\to& \coprod_X K* &\to& KX \\
\downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow\\
Y &\to& \coprod_Y K* &\to& KY 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your point.  Maybe my comment in reply to Derek's comment above clarifies things?

Comment: There are a few clarifications in the opening post.